# SqlCommand - conversion from varchar to int

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hello I have got this code :

```
SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ... WHERE akce=" + zakce.Text, spojeni);

spojeni.Open();

object vysledek2 = sc2.ExecuteScalar(); // This is the exception line
```

I'm receving following Exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)
> Conversion failed when
>   converting the varchar value '137000-01' to data type int.

On the exception line when I set the breakpoint on vysledek2 is null and then the exception occurs.

Comment: Consider changing your variable names to English - this is quite difficult to read :)

Comment: Also you have a typo between `sumpayments` and `FROM`.

Comment: BTW - please see "Bobby Tables" - via Google, Bing, etc

Comment: Yes, this is a really good way to code if you want to become another SQL injection statistic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never. Ever. Concatenate. Input.

```
SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(ISNULL(payments,0)) AS sumpaymentsFROM clientpayments WHERE akce=@acke", spojeni);
sc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("acke", zakce.Text);
```

Also - commands, connections, etc are all `IDisposable` - you should use `using` around each of them.

Comment: Hell Marc, thanks for respond, I tried what you advised but still got the same exception, don't you have an idea where did I made a mistake?

Comment: @Marek:- As a peice of advice why you want to correct your mistake with a bad coding practice??

Comment: @Marek that cannot throw the same exception - there is no string/into conversion here. check you have built etc, and check the exact message

Comment: @RahulTripathi I guess the `OP` may not know **What's wrong with his code**, this of course **solves** his problem but **He doesn't have a chance to know why his code didn't work** (Of course unless he took some look at some other answers).

Answer (score 1):

```
        const string sqlSelect = @"SELECT ... WHERE akce=@akce";
        using (spojeni = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
        using(var command = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect,spojeni))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@akce", zakce.Text);
            command.Connection.Open();
            object vysledek2 = command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try changing

```
SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(ISNULL(payments,0)) AS sumpaymentsFROM clientpayments WHERE akce=" + zakce.Text, spojeni);
```

to something like

```
SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(ISNULL(payments,0)) AS sumpaymentsFROM clientpayments WHERE akce='" + zakce.Text + "'", spojeni);
```

Secondly, have a look at what [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is and how to use [parametereized queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter).